# What is the optimal way to pass styles in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am wondering what is the best way to pass in styles. I understand that when using StyleSheet.create, it makes the style once so that it can always be referred to by a number. The component in question looks as follows:

```
<Text
  ellipsizeMode={ ellipsizeMode }
  numberOfLines={ numberOfLines }
  style={ [stylesheet.defaultText, styles, fontTypes[type], { color }] }
>
 { children }
</Text>
```

When I use the inspector, I see that 4 styles are passed through the bridge, two of which were from a stylesheet.create, and two others are object literals.

Would it be advisable to clean the style array up, either by removing empty object literals, or combining them? I'm not sure how much this even matters. Does anyone have insight into the nitty-gritty of how styles are passed from the JS layer to the native layer, and how is the best way to address this?

Answer (score 0):

Optimal way is:

1. Create component for your (if you this component will you re use if not create only styles file)
2. Create styles file via:

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     text: {
              fontSize: 22
              }
    });

   3. import styles in your component or where to use it

   import { styles } from './styles';

   4. and use it for example:

   Text<\Text>

That's all.

Comment: Yeah, I know that that is the ideal way, but as I asked in my question what about when you need to combine styles, including some from a StyleSheet and some dynamically created from objects?

Comment: You can do this way:

const [dynamicValue, setDynamicValue] = useState(1);

<View style=[styles.firstStyle, {fontSize: dynamicValue}] />